# Create authentication when someone accesses httpd in centOs

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have CentOS 6.6, What I want is: When someone accesses the  `/var/www/html` on his/her browser, I want an authentication bar to pop up and fill in his/her username and password. This is because I want httpd over my whole router and there could be someone at the office that can just go in with only the IP-address of CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `htpasswd` to secure your web directory . follow the bellow steps.

> **step1** :

go to your web directory that you want to secure for example /var/www/html/data . here create any user that want to allow using bellow command :

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd any_user
```

where use `-c` to create first  user if you want to create more user than use only `htpasswd  .htpasswd second_user`

> **step2** :

create a file with name .htaccess and do entry like this

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
AuthName "provide authentication to access page" 
AuthType Basic 
require valid-user
```

now try to open in browser it will ask you usename and password that you created .